# How to place in a document a VCard using a psbarcode?

Tags: pstricks, pst-barcode

I would like to put a QRCode that contains contact information ([VCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard)). However I don't know how to encode the newline character so VCard is correctly read.

Here is a sample document with QRCode without newline chars (**UPDATED:** I changed the example to one from [de.wikipedia.org](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard), because my iphone qrcode reader does not properly processes the example from [en.wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard))):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}


\begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}(1in,1in)
    \obeylines
    \psbarcode{%
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:Mustermann;Max
FN:Max Mustermann
ORG:Wikipedia
URL:http://de.wikipedia.org/
EMAIL;TYPE=INTERNET:max.mustermann@example.org
TEL;TYPE=voice,work,pref:+49 1234 56788
ADR;TYPE=intl,work,postal,parcel:;;Musterstraße 1;Musterstadt;;12345;Germany
END:VCARD
}{width=2.0 height=2.0}{qrcode}%
    \end{pspicture} 


\end{document}
```

I have found a similar question on [tug.org](http://tug.org/mailman/htdig/pstricks/2011/008716.html), the conclusion was that you need to modify the generated [PostScript](http://tug.org/mailman/htdig/pstricks/2011/008720.html). I wonder if there is another solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does the following code do the right thing?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}

{\obeylines\gdef^^M{^^J}%
 \catcode`\@=0 %
 \catcode`\\=12 %
 @gdef@n{\n}}
\begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}(1in,1in)
    \obeylines
    \psbarcode{%
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:Gump;Forrest
FN:Forrest Gump
ORG:Bubba Gump Shrimp Co.
TITLE:Shrimp Man
TEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:(111) 555-1212
TEL;TYPE=HOME,VOICE:(404) 555-1212
ADR;TYPE=WORK:;;100 Waters Edge;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America
LABEL;TYPE=WORK:100 Waters Edge\n Baytown, LA 30314\n United States of America
ADR;TYPE=HOME:;;42 Plantation St.;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America
LABEL;TYPE=HOME:42 Plantation St.\n Baytown, LA 30314\n United States of America
EMAIL;TYPE=PREF,INTERNET:forrestgump@example.com
REV:20080424T195243Z
END:VCARD
}{width=2.0 height=2.0}{qrcode}%
    \end{pspicture} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: I have an additional question. Why the command does not work when I put the pspicture in tabular.

Comment: @Skarab: That would be because all the tokens going into one tabular entry get scanned before they are executed, and so the category changes happen too late to do any good. You can do `\setbox0\hbox{…}` where `…` stands for the entire `pspicture` environment, and then use `\box0` in the tabular. (Note that the standard LaTeX commands `\savebox` and `\sbox` also scan their argument before executing, which is why I resort to TeX primitives here.)

Comment: Another solution, which should work without the trick of the previous comment, is to drop the `\obeylines` and the definition of `^^M` and instead manually insert `^^J` at the end of each line of the vcard.

Comment: I've implemented, based on the above mentioned example, my own vcard. Can't read it properly for example using [MeeScan (ver. 0.0.12)](http://store.ovi.com/content/231518?clickSource=search&pos=1). Is it the reader's fault?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris: I have no idea. If other barcode scanners can read it, then yes. Could you tell the difference between a failure to read the scan and a failure to parse the resulting text as a vcard?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen MeeScan seems to read everything as instructed. With one annoying (to me, the ignorant!) detail: every line in the "result" begins with `advance par@deathcycles @ne` followed by what is, indeed, stated. Trying (to) `Open contact`, returns _Can't open this contact card because it's damaged_. Is it the size of generated (square) QR code (I measured it to be 2.9cm^2 on paper)?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris This doesn't happen for me. Do you run standard latex? The code doesn't work for me in pdflatex. What do you see on the terminal if you insert `\show^^M` just after `\obeylines`? The expected answer is `^^M=\par`.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen working under (K)ubuntu 12.04, I compile the same code (using `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}` and `\usepackage{pstricks}`, `\usepackage{pst-barcode}` once using [Kile](http://kile.sourceforge.net/) (LaTeX > ForwardDVI) and once using [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/) (View DVI). They do not generate the same QR code. Kile provides a working code while LyX gives a more "complex" result and non-working, i.e. it throws out the errors previously mentioned. So it's me to blame (mis-)using LyX (?).

Comment: @NikosAlexandris: Could be that LyX does more than a standard LaTeX does. I'm afraid I can't help you with that; I suggest you ask a separate question if you need help figuring it out.