# How to generate QR code for iCalendar event?

Tags: pdftex, pst-barcode, barcodes

I would like to include in a pdf file a QR code containing information from a [iCalendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) event.

Here it is the code to generate a simple event for an iCalendar:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:event
DTSTART:20110913T130000Z
DTEND:20110913T140000Z
END:VEVENT
```

I would like to generate a QR code for that text so I get it from my Android phone and automatically insert a new event in my Calendar app.

**EDIT 1**:

I found out in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10584/generating-2d-barcodes) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1429/latex-package-to-generate-qr-codes) post how you can generate a QR code. I generated a QR code but my Android app was not able to understand that the text was a iCalendar event.

**EDIT 2:**

After @Yossi suggestion I add the following code. That was supposed to create a valid QR code with an iCal event. That is the same code that I used to generating other QR codes but it is not working as I want with iCal events.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{pspicture}(0.7in,0.7in)
\psbarcode{%
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:event
DTSTART:20110913T130000Z
DTEND:20110913T140000Z
END:VEVENT
}{}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

And here it is the command I used for compiling my tex file:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape
```

I can generate the QR code but for some reason the text encoded is not a valid iCal event.

Comment: In the event that nobody has a solution involving TeX, you can do that using Inkscape.

Comment: see http://xaphire.de/recipes/?p=344

Comment: @Raphink can you give me some link to how generate QR code in Inkscape?

Comment: @Yossi: don't you want to make that an answer?

Comment: @PinoSan: Inkscape can do Datamatrix in Extensions -> Render -> Barcode - Datamatrix.

Comment: @PinoSan: I was just putting in a placeholder... ;-)

Comment: Upon reading the EDIT1: I think that the question is misplaced. This is a problem for android or smartphone website, the latex related question has been asked and answered in the past: -1 vote to close.

Comment: Does the app work with the sample at [http://www.qrdvark.com/qr-formats/ical/](http://www.qrdvark.com/qr-formats/ical/), referenced in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547927/how-to-generate-qr-code-with-icalender-in-it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547927/how-to-generate-qr-code-with-icalender-in-it)? If so, does the same data produce a workable QRcode using the available LaTeX solutions?

Comment: @mas My app work fine with your first link QR so it is not a problem of my Android app. Yossi please can you remove the -1 vote. It's not a problem of my Android app but only how to generate a valid QR include a iCalendar event.

Comment: I found here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20520/how-to-place-in-a-document-a-vcard-using-a-psbarcode the solution to my own question. But I cannot answer myself before the next 7 hour. You have only to replace the code for the vCard with my code for the iCalendar event

Comment: @mas I was able to add a new event with my app and the sample QR code at http://www.qrdvark.com/qr-formats/ical/

Comment: I can't. but the question as it is written is almost entirely a duplicate of another. So, if you rewrite the question using code that should create the QR-code but doesn't work for creating the iCal event, then the question would be relevent, and I'll take my -1 off.

Comment: @Yossi: This question can be seen as a specialization of [Generating 2d barcodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10584/generating-2d-barcodes) and therefore is not an exact duplicate. The issue is not the actual generation but to generate the barcode the right way.

Comment: Its was very unclear to me in the beginning...any how...+0 now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The QR code generated by following was recognised as an iCalendar event by [Qrafter](http://itunes.apple.com/app/qrafter-qr-code-reader-generator/id416098700) on an iPad:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(2in,2in)
\psbarcode{BEGIN:VEVENT^^J%
SUMMARY:event^^J%
DTSTART:20110913T130000Z^^J%
DTEND:20110913T140000Z^^J%
END:VEVENT}
{height=2 width=2}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

The `^^J` are needed for newlines. If you prefer, you can also play around with the catcodes to avoid having to type `^^J`, as demonstrated in this related question on [generating QR codes containing vCards](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20520/how-to-place-in-a-document-a-vcard-using-a-psbarcode).

Comment: As suggested by @mas in this [link](http://www.qrdvark.com/qr-formats/ical/) the tags BEGIN:VCALENDAR and END:VCALENDAR can be removed if you have problems. I tested without this tags and still works.

Comment: @PinoSan Thanks, it works with my barcode scanning app too. I've edited my answer by removing the BEGIN and END VCALENDAR lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a detailed answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\begin{document}
  \begin{pspicture}(1in,1in)
    \psbarcode{test string}{}{qrcode}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

You'll need to use LaTeX and not PDFLaTeX since the package uses pstricks.

Comment: `xelatex` will also work.

Comment: Here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20520/how-to-place-in-a-document-a-vcard-using-a-psbarcode I found my own solution with pdflatex instead of latex. For using pdflatex you have to use the command "pdflatex --shell-escape"

Comment: Less detailed than a [previous answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1431/2580), though :-)